# TSQL - Order of WHERE clause change execution time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a very heavy query (built to test this behaviour) that use some filters and a LIKE on a TEXT column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT somefields
FROM sometable
WHERE customer = 9
      AND request LIKE '%FILE.DLL%' -- LIKE at second place
      AND creationDate >= '02/08/2014'
      AND lastEditDate >= '02/08/2014'
      AND officeCode = 'PF'
ORDER BY creationDate DESC ,
         creationTime DESC;
```

This query runs in 29-35 minutes, with no records found (i'm ok with that).

But if I edit this query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT somefields
FROM sometable
WHERE customer = 9
      AND creationDate >= '02/08/2014'
      AND lastEditDate >= '02/08/2014'
      AND officeCode = 'PF'
      AND request LIKE '%FILE.DLL%' -- LIKE at last place
ORDER BY creationDate DESC ,
         creationTime DESC;
```

This second query runs in 19 minutes, so more that 30% faster.

While I've red so many questions about the order of the WHERE clause that *should* not matter, why does the same query, with the LIKE just being placed in different positions, change the execution time so heavily?

I'm my head this is a product of SQL Server short-circuiting conditions, so leaving LIKE, the heaviest condition, as the last to evaluate, the engine first excludes most rows based on the previous conditions, reducing the amount of evaluations done on the LIKE condition.

Am I wrong?

EDIT: I've executed both queries with `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` before.

Comment: sql server does NOT do short circuiting of the where conditions. Look at both execution plans and you'll see where the difference is.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that this has more to do with cached plans, where changing the query string resolves to recalculate (wasting time and effort) and potentially even go with a different plan altogether. You could clear the cache for the next time, and / or include an actual execution plan for both queries so you can compare what's actually going on.

Comment: I've executed both queries with DBCC FREEPROCCACHE before it.

Comment: are you sure sometable is actually a table ? Are you sure that your TEXT column is actually TEXT, I hope it is varchar(xxx) ? How long does the query take if you change it to SELECT count(*), how many rows are in your table

Comment: @t-clausen.dk sometable is actually more tables in JOIN, mixed INNER and LEFT, I simplifed the whole query. The request column's datatype is exactly TEXT, not VARCHAR(x). I could run a SELECT count(*) without filters on the entire sets of table, but it will be long. The 2 main tables have 12.894.326 records and 3.976.904 records.

Comment: TEXT is deprecated and can't be trusted, your problem could also be in your joins

Comment: @t-clausen.dk ok, but that does not answer my question. Why does moving around the LIKE clause, change the execution time so much? Why should it be related to JOINs?

Comment: @mordack550 because very often performance issues are caused by crazy joins. If i could solve your problem with the given information, I would have posted an answer instead of a comment. I still don't believe your query is affected by the position of your LIKE in your WHERE statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71176/discussion-between-t-clausen-dk-and-mordack550).

Comment: @MladenPrajdic You're right, I used short-circuit wrongly. What I meant to say is Evaluation Order.

Comment: How can you expect help with query you don't actually post?  Post the actual queries and actual query plans.

Comment: Question: if query "E" has the `like` early in the where clause, and query "L" has it later, what happens when you run the queries in (relatively) quick succession like E - L - E - L - E - L? Is the performance consistent (always slower/faster)? Based on a recent personal experience, my first guess would be something to do with out of date/refreshing of statistics.

Comment: @PhilipKelley yeah the performance difference is consistent. Before each query I clean cached plans (DBCC FREEPROCCACHE) and run. That's why I made this question. That's strange to me too.

Comment: FREEPROCCACHE has no effect on statistics, but with the times reported it's clearly not a statistics issue. (What about DROPCLEANBUFFERS?) As per the first comment, how do the two execution plans differ?

Comment: @PhilipKelley same execution plans, same query cost.

Comment: How are you determining the execution time?  Using the profiler?  Or by examining what the execution plan says about the percent of time each query takes up?  It often happens that execution plans will say things take exactly equal percentages of time that, in actuality, take different times.

Comment: Just a silly question, I suppose that you tried running the first query again and saw it was 29 minutes again?

Comment: @Ako of course. I repeated the test 3 times. I will try tomorrow with DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

Comment: I would be interested in the io statistics output, because the problem is interesting.

Comment: @mordack550 Did you retest or found something ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the indexes of your table.
If they are out of date or the fields of your index are ordered in different ways could cause this different times of calculation.